# Modify or block contents JS function with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, overriding

I need to block writing to LocalStorage. So when the function `localstorage.setItem()` is called, I need to change it's behaviour or block.
I have my content.js in `"content_scripts"` of manifest

Here are possible ways (I can't find anything on all of them):

**1) Event handler of storage change**

I've tried

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
    console.log("storage event occured here");
});
```

But I need detection of function call in the same tab (through extension).

**2) Override system function `localstorage.setItem()`**

It works if I will write in console

```
localStorage.setItem = function(){
    console.log('modified');
  }
```

But **not** if in content.js

Also tried to add to manifest `"run_at" : "document_start"` for content_scripts

**3) Event handler of setItem function call**

Is it possible to set trigger/handler for custom function call? I know handlers like click, mouseover.. but on function calls - not.

Comment: 1) Content scripts run in an isolated world so you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879), 2) You might want to intercept localStorage.key = 'foo' too by replacing window.localStorage with a `Proxy`, look for examples.

Comment: Thank you! It's working

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to inject script file through contents script. Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)

**content.js**

```
var inj = document.createElement('script');
inj.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('blockaccess.js');
inj.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(inj);
```

**blockaccess.js**

```
Storage.setItem = localStorage.setItem = sessionStorage.setItem = function(){
  console.log('Blocked Storage setItem()');
}
```